# find lowest unique bid

Tags: php, mysql

My database looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to find the lowest unique bidder for a auction of a product. I also want to display the username of that lowest unique bidder. That lowest unique bid is based on `productid` where every product have different id.

Please help. I've tried the following code:

```
<?php
    $username=$_SESSION['userName']; 


$sql="SELECT bidamount,
       userName
      FROM bid
      WHERE description = '$username'
     AND bidamount =
    (SELECT min(lowest_bid.bidamount)
     FROM bid lowest_bid
     WHERE lowest_bid.description = '$username'
     GROUP BY lowest_bid.bidamount HAVING count(DISTINCT lowest_bid.userName) = 1
     ORDER BY bidamount LIMIT 1)";

    $query=mysql_query('$sql') or die("problem with query");
?>
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: What results are you getting? Are you getting any errors? Include more information in your original question by editing it.

Comment: getting error like problem with query

Comment: Can you wirte your error which you getting?

Comment: i am not geeting any error but it is not displaying username of lowest unique bidder

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the single quotes around your query. They prevent your variable from being interpolated.

```
$query=mysql_query($sql) ;
```

Comment: but i m not able to display userName who have lowest unique bid

Comment: Do you get an error? You may want to set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to help us help you.

Comment: ya got erro and it is solved thanks a lot for that but my question is there be any problem with query so that we can find lowest unique bid based on product id and display that lowest unique bidder username

Comment: hey any can help me plz

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need a subquery in your query.
I think you miss DESC in ORDER BY

```
$sql="SELECT bidamount,
       userName
      FROM bid
      WHERE description = '$username'
      ORDER BY bidamount DESC LIMIT 1 ";
```

Comment: Do you try with my sql query ?

Comment: hey i want find lowest unique bid depend on product id because every product have diff. id so when product is hited it got product id and then depend on product id it will find lowest unique bid and then display username of that lowest unique bidder.